# Adding delay to jquery event on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, children, show-hide, onmouseover

I am trying to add a simple delay to a mouseover event of a child and having difficulties. (Still learning!)

This enables me to show the popup after a delay, but shows all of them simultaneously:

```
onmouseover='setTimeout(function() { $(\".skinnyPopup\").show(); }, 600)'
```

and this works to show only the popup I want with no delay:

```
onmouseover='$(this).children(\".skinnyPopup\").show()'
```

but the combination does not:

```
onmouseover='setTimeout(function() { $(this).children(\".skinnyPopup\").show(); }, 600)'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define what `this` is when it executes, something like this would work:

```
setTimeout($.proxy(function() { $(this).children(".skinnyPopup").show(); }, this), 600)
```

Or just use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), like this:

```
$(this).children(".skinnyPopup").delay(600).show(0);
```

Both of the above are quick fixes, I suggest you move away from inline handlers and check out an [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) method (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621574/jquery-why-unobtrusive-javascript-document-ready-function-rather-than-onclick/621589#621589) by [Russ Cam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831/russ-cam) for some great reasons), for example:

```
$(function() {
  $('selector').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".skinnyPopup").delay(600).show(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 - I also agree with Nick about the move away from inline handlers.

Comment: Thank you, that helped my understanding. Seems everything becomes quirky if done inline. Not sure why, but I sure know to avoid it now!

Comment: @TLK - welcome :) if it resolves your question be sure to accept as an answer, if not let me know what problem you're still having :)

Comment: Sorry, haven't logged on in a while and didn't notice that option. (n00b) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because `this` is bound to the global context, not the element. Use something like the following instead:

```
// put this in your document head -- replace element with a selector for the elements you want
$(function () {
    $(element).bind("mouseover", function () {
       var e = $(this);
       setTimeout(function () { e.children(".skinnyPopup").show(); }, 600);
    });
});
```

If you're adamant about inline event handlers, the following should also work:

```
onmouseover='var self = this; setTimeout(function() { $(self).children(\".skinnyPopup\").show(); }, 600)'
```

Comment: Thank you! Have not used bind() yet. Have to check that out next.